# How To Filter on a subquery in Amazon Cloudwatch Insights

Tags: aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Are you able to run a filter with a subquery in Cloudwatch Insights? I would like to take the requestID and find all logs related to it. I can run the queries separately but was trying to do it one.

Something like this:

```
filter @requestId in (filter @message like /Id 26313/ fields @requestId sort @timestamp desc limit 1)
| fields @message
| sort @timestamp desc
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. Subqueries are not currently possible.

Comment: Thank you for verifying I wasn't missing something. I hope AWS adds this feature in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Same question has been asked in the official AWS forum: https://repost.aws/questions/QU4IlWVGcbT3WA1PdhKCtkCw/nested-quires-for-cloud-insights

Their answer:

> We already have an internal feature request for the same and I have
> gone ahead and associated this query to it in order to further
> escalate this feature. However please note that I cannot provide you
> with an ETA as to when this will be available.
>
> As a possible workaround you can achieve this by programmatically
> running insights queries using StartQuery/GetQueryResults APIs[1][2]
> via custom code/script.