# How to write AWS Cloudwatch Insights subquery

Tags: aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have 2 queries below which want to join together and write AWS cloudwatch query so that 1 query depends on outcome of another query.

Query1:
`fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @requestId | sort @timestamp desc | filter @message like "sometext"`

Query2:
`fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @requestId | sort @timestamp desc | filter @message like "someanothertext"`

Need a query as below:
`fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @requestId | sort @timestamp desc | filter @message like "someanothertext" and @requestId IN (fields @requestId | filter @message like "sometext")`

I looked if I can do a JOIN as well, but couldn't find syntax or an example.
Only thing I noticed is that UNION could be used to combine AWS queries, but that will not solve my problem.
Appreciate your help!

Looks like a similar question was asked in 2020, and AWS insisted that they have created a feature, but I haven't seen it implemented yet after 3 years now, anyone else has any other updates?

[How To Filter on a subquery in Amazon Cloudwatch Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61964409/how-to-filter-on-a-subquery-in-amazon-cloudwatch-insights)